# Pan/Zoom Google Map on Search

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the below in a Google Map which allows me to query a Fusion Table for a given name as searched by the user.  How do I set up Google Maps to pan/zoom based on the search results returned?

```
//Text based search
function changeSearch() {
  var searchSearch = document.getElementById('searchSearch').value.replace("'", "\\'");
  layer.setQuery("SELECT 'lat' FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'Name' CONTAINS IGNORING CASE '" + searchSearch + "'");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FusionTablesLayer does not give you enough information to pan and zoom the map based on the result.

The best solution is to query the Fusion Tables SQL API (using a server) for the same data, and calculate the bounding box which includes all the results returned by the SQL API. You could do this, for example, with a PHP script running on your server, which you can call from Javascript using AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

I hate it when others tell me to read the documentation, but in this case unless I am missing something you should defenatly have a browse thru it http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map.

```
panTo(latLng:LatLng)
panToBounds(latLngBounds:LatLngBounds)
setCenter(latlng:LatLng)
setZoom(zoom:number)
fitBounds(bounds:LatLngBounds)
```

Plenty to choose from and many more :)